# How to hard code 7 int positions?

Tags: java, android

I am using this method to retrieve some images.

The only problem is is where

```
aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
```

Position is i dont know how to get the position for each image in order to set the tag in my code.

```
 i.setTag(mImageURLs[position]);
```

As you see myRemoteimages has 7 strings and thats all. How can i hard code. the int Position to just have 7 positions?

```
public void RetrieveImages() {

    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    String[] mImageURLs = {
        urlImage1, urlImage2, urlImage3, urlImage4, urlImage5, urlImage6,
        urlImage7};

    String[] myRemoteImages = {
        imageUrl, imageUrl2, imageUrl3, imageUrl4,
        imageUrl5, imageUrl6, imageUrl7};

    URL aURL = null;

    try {
        aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("ImageLoader", "Remote images set");
    i.setTag(mImageURLs[position]);                   

    URI imageUri = null;

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("imageUri", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsEdit = myPrefs.edit();

    // Setting the Uri of aURL to imageUri.
    try {
        imageUri = aURL.toURI();
        myPrefsEdit.putString("uris", imageUri.toString());
        myPrefsEdit.commit();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question feels a little ambiguous, and to my mind there are a couple of answers, depending on what the OP is actually looking for.  There are also some odd things being done in this code...

- The two arrays you create, `mImageURLs` and `myRemoteImages`, both contain conceptually identical string names.  This is confusing, and will lead to maintenance problems.  In addition, because the strings used appear to be instance variables, you should likely have the **arrays** as the instance variables, saving you the trouble of declaring 14 (and eventually more) string variables (and the related maintenance trouble of dealing with them).  Declaring variable names like `imageUrl`, `imageUrl2`, ... `imageUrl7` is often a sign that the problem is being implemented problematically - at the very least, if there are different strings for *distinct* things, they should be named as such (`backImage`, `forwardImage`, etc).  Besides the issue that `urlImage` and `imageUrl1` 'appear' to be missing(due to the difference in the naming scheme).
- Your code prints a stack trace; this is possibly a problem when putting the code on the device.  Your average consumer probably doesn't *know* java, and wouldn't know what to do with an error log if it bit them.  You probably *should* be logging errors somehow, but this may have to be disabled if you don't have some sort of reporting tool to *get* the logs.  Oh, and just name the exception you're catching `e` - it's the standard, you've already got them out-of-order and it's not like they can be accessed outside of the catch block.
- It looks like there may be a couple of smaller methods trying to break out of here.  Without knowing specifically what you're trying to accomplish, it's a little difficult to know what those should contain.

---

If you know that a *specific* index in the array will *always* contain the desired URI (and you're only using one of them), you can go ahead and hard code that.  Preferrably, you use a constant, which you then reference elsewhere as necessary:

```
i.setTag(mImageURLs[HOME_PAGE_IMAGE_ARRAY_INDEX]);
```

Of course, at that point (especially if you're declaring the array locally...), you may as well use the actual string:

```
i.setTag(urlImage3);
```

This also saves you the cost of dealing with an array.

---

If you need to go through all the images in an array...
There are two ways to loop over an array in Java:  the `foreach` loop (which I'm not sure if android supports), and the standard `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mImageURLs.length(); i++) {
    i.setTag(mImageURLs[i]);
}
```

This has the added benefit that, if you always want to display *all* the strings in the array, this 'automatically' expands to deal with it.  Whether exception handling belongs inside or outside of the array depends on the design, but I suspect that it likely belongs inside here...

Comment: +1 just for your effort, but rather ask him what he tries to do. The code makes no sense at several points ;-)

Comment: The last half is what i need. Do you think my code is problematic?